# Update many rows in one table (long execution time)

Tags: php, mysqli

I have one table (cp_article) with arround 63k rows with 4 columns (cp_articleID, cp_articleNR, cp_articleNAME, cp_articleDRAWING) and I want to update cp_articleDRAWING with $i WHERE cp_articleNR = $NR

Before I read from DB all cp_articleNR and put in an array to count it and use it in my for loop.
This is at the moment just for testing, later I want to put a patch to a PDF file in cp_articleDRAWING but the performance is really bad. Below you can find my code, the first function is for getting all cp_articleNR and the second function is to update the cp_articleDRAWING with a rising number where cp_articleNR = $NR from an array

In 120 seconds I can update around 1700-2100 rows, on my dev-server around 3000 rows. My personal feeling is that is too slow.

```
//Get all articleNR from DB and put in Array
function getArticleFromDB()
{
    try {
        require '../includes/dbh.php';
        $sql = "SELECT cp_articleNR FROM cp_article";
        $ergebnis = $db_link->query($sql);
        $array = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ergebnis)) {
            $array[] = $row;
        }
        //Export to array
        return $array;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo "Fehler: " . $ex->getMessage();
    }
}


function updateDrawingPath()
{
    //Datenbankverbindung
    require '../includes/dbh.php';
    //Schreibe Artikel in Array
    $array = getArticleFromDB();
    //Count all entrys in Array
    $count = count($array);
    //
    $stmt = $db_link->prepare("UPDATE cp_article SET cp_articleDRAWING = ? WHERE cp_articleNR = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $i, $nr);
    //Execute loop until $count is reached
    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $i = $i;
        $nr = $array[$i]["cp_articleNR"];
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $db_link->close();
}

//execute function
updateDrawingPath();
```

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Remove that useless try-catch. I don't know where you learned to do that but that is only going to hurt you in the future. Also, do not require connection inside the function; use function arguments to pass the connection into the function.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this code. Your SELECT doesn't have an order by but then you use `$i` to update the same rows? What's the point in selecting any data from the database? You should be using DB transactions if you are making so many operations separately, but then there is a question why do you do all of them in PHP? Why can't you do it all in SQL?

Comment: Your whole PHP code comes down to something like this (when you define ordering sequence of course): `UPDATE cp_article JOIN ( WITH NewSequence AS ( SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) as ID_New FROM cp_article ) SELECT * FROM NewSequence ) sq ON sq.id = products.id SET cp_article.cp_articleDRAWING =ID_New`

Comment: First sry for my not perfect english...

Comment: To your first and scound answer:
I buyed a book and thy recommend to use mysqli (better performance) but i know PDO is better for different DB-Servers (MSSQL, MySQL, etc.)
And also there they wrote to do it witch try-catch...
I think these two points i can change!
To your third and fourth answer i will need some time to understood.

But to you question why not do everything in sql, i can say i have first to read a directory on my server and then i have to put the path according to articleNR in the DB.

Comment: Lets say my articleNR = 75400561 and my articleDRAWING = pdf/75400561_FilamentHolder.pdf
Later on my overview i want to have a table with NR, NAME and <a href> to DRAWING
for that i created a virtual directory (pdf) in apache and the raw data comes from \\server\data\drawing\my_drawing.pdf
From \\server i want to take only the file name, and the VD is \\server\data\drawing
So i can use href... to www.mysite.de/pdf/my_drawing.pdf

I hope you understand a little what is my goal to reach.

Comment: If any book recommends using mysqli over PDO then it's not worth buying.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: hahaha okay i will send the book back ^^